# Which smartphones can have Ubuntu software?

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

I have a smartphone Lg Optimus 3D max. Can my Android have Ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You've tagged your question with the older Ubuntu for Android, but I think you mean Ubuntu Touch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the XDA website. Some one says they have managed.

He has left instruction.

[Ubuntu 10.10 on LG Optimus 3D xD](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1164486)

Hope it helps

Comment: Have you read the replies? I think it's not available anymore: "link dead..." "There is no ubuntu.rar file to download". Also, Ubuntu 10.10 is very old.

Comment: There maybe more update versions on the web, That one was the first result of a very quick google search